# Generating a series from a predefined date (PG)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to generate a series of monthly dates from a starting date, which happens to be the date of the oldest user in my users table.

Whilst I can select some dates quite easily;

```
SELECT generate_series(
now(),
now() + '5 months'::interval,
'1 month'::interval);
```

and can select the date I need to start at:

```
SELECT to_date( to_char(CAST(min(created_at) AS DATE),'yyyy-MM') || '-01','yyyy-mm-dd') from users
```

How can I combine the two so that I'm selecting every month up until now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, it can be even simpler. :)

```
SELECT generate_series(
          date_trunc('year', min(created_at))
        , now()
        , interval '1 month') AS month;
FROM   users;
```

More about [date_trunc in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC).

Or, if you actually want the data type `date` instead of `timestamp with time zone`:

```
SELECT generate_series(
          date_trunc('year', min(created_at))
        , now()
        , interval '1 month')::date AS month;
FROM   users;
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's pretty simple:

```
SELECT generate_series(
(SELECT to_date( to_char(CAST(min(created_at) AS DATE),'yyyy-MM') || '-01','yyyy-mm-dd') from users),
now(),
'1 month'::interval) as month;
```